# How to create / access a shared folder in a linux system?

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, shared

We are setting up two server systems. One of which will host a 3rd party application which will by default save certain data on a local folder:
     /opt/application/common/recordings

How do I create a "writable share" on the other server (with appropriate permissions), so that all these files from the first server are saved on the second.

In the installation of this 3rd party applicaiton, I can only specify the folder. I cannot modify anything else.

Comment: Not a programming question. Tick Tock Tick Tock. This question is going to close in mmmmm.. 29 mins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System), [CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifs), even [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sshfs); pretty much any networked/distributed file system - [take your pick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Distributed_file_systems).

Comment: Hi Piskvor - both the servers are going to be RHEL5. Are the systems you propose replacements for the OS or supplementary to it?

Comment: @tzmatt7447: Those are filesystems that can be shared amongst multiple computers. They are supported in must Linuxes, including RHEL - so they're installed in addition to the OS.

Comment: Thank you - since this public read/write share is the only thing we're planning on doing for file-transfer between 2 trusted computers, could you make a recommendation on what we should use?

Comment: @tzmatt7447: look at this answer at SuperUser - seems to favor NFSv4: http://serverfault.com/questions/14577/what-network-file-sharing-protocol-has-the-best-performance-and-reliability